# Tim sort implementation working at low array size but crashing at high

Tags: java, sorting

Basically i built this rudementary tim sort built for a simple project and it works with a sub of 32 all the way up to 1000 integers (the next thing i tried was 5000) and then it crashes with a index out of bounds exeception i tried increasing the sub to 64 but it just dosent seem to work i was wondering if anyone could tell me what im doing wrong here.

```
public static void timSort(List<Comparable> nums) {
        int sub = 32;
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i += sub)  
        { 
            if((nums.size() -1) < (i + 31)) {
                inPlaceInsertion(nums, i, (nums.size() - 1));
            }else {
                inPlaceInsertion(nums, i, (i + 31)); 
            }
        } 

        for (int size = sub; size < nums.size(); size = 2 * size)  
        { 

            for (int left = 0; left < nums.size(); left += 2 * size)  
            {
                int mid = left + size - 1; 
                int right;
                if((nums.size() - 1) < (left + 2 * size - 1)) {
                    right = nums.size() -1;
                }else {
                    right = left + 2 * size -1;
                }
                merge(nums, left, mid, right); 
            } 
        } 
    }

public static void inPlaceInsertion(List<Comparable> nums, int first, int last){
        for(int i = first; i <= last; i++){
            Comparable hold = nums.get(i);
            int j;
            steps++;
            for(j = i; j > first && hold.compareTo(nums.get(j - 1)) < 0; j--) {
                nums.set(j, nums.get(j - 1));
                steps+=4;
            }
            nums.set(j, hold);
            steps++;
        }   
    }   

private static void merge(List<Comparable> nums, int first, int mid, int last){
         List<Comparable> newList = new  ArrayList<Comparable>();

         int loopCountA = 0;
         int loopCountB = 0;
         while(true) {
             if(loopCountB == (last - mid)) {
                 while(first + loopCountA <= mid) {
                     newList.add(nums.get(first + loopCountA)); loopCountA++;
                     steps++;
                 }
                 break;
             }else if(first + loopCountA > mid) {
                 while(loopCountB < (last - mid)) {
                     newList.add(nums.get(mid + (loopCountB + 1))); loopCountB++;
                     steps++;
                 }
                 break;
             }else { 
                 if(nums.get(mid + (loopCountB + 1)).compareTo(nums.get(first + loopCountA)) < 0)  {
                     // here is where error is (line above)
                     newList.add(nums.get(mid + (loopCountB + 1)));
                     steps += 5;
                     loopCountB++;
                 }else {
                     newList.add(nums.get(first + loopCountA));
                     steps += 5;
                     loopCountA++;
                 }
             }
         }       

         for(int i = 0; (i - 1) < (last - first); i++) {
             nums.set(first + i, newList.get(i));
             steps+=2;
         }
    }
```

Here's the error...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 5024 out of bounds for length 5000
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:372)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:458)
    at Sorts.merge(Sorts.java:772)
    at Sorts.timSort(Sorts.java:1193)
    at Sorts.sortMenu(Sorts.java:255)
    at Sorts.main(Sorts.java:33)
```

Simple main method which demonstrates it not working

```
        int depthLimit 
        = (int)(2 * Math.floor(Math.log(nums.size()) / 
                             Math.log(2)));  
        introSort(nums, 0, nums.size() -1, depthLimit);
```

Comment: You will need to include the full stack trace, and also the code for the `inPlaceInsertion` and `merge` methods since the code you've shown us doesn't do any accessing by index, so the exception can't occur here. Ideally, also include the input you're testing with, so it's a [mcve].

Comment: sorry dont know what i was thinking but i added all of that

Comment: The exception is thrown on line 772, in the `merge` method - could you identify which line that is by labelling it with a comment?

Comment: there ive added a comment where the error is occouring